# Function in Cloud App Engine cannot read 'seconds'?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-firestore

Yesterday, I redeployed a google app engine cron job cron.yaml and app.yaml for a function that would run every minute. Now, however, I am receiving the error message

```
Cannot read property 'seconds' of null
    at Function.fromProto (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/timestamp.js:91:46)
    at _firestore.request.then.resp (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:472:42)
```

I don't think this is an error with the code in the function, as I have redeployed the function. In addition, I have tried accessing the aforementioned file and can find no trace of any problem. Is this a problem with the deployment? How can I resolve this issue?

EDIT:

I also started receiving this

```
    The behavior for Date objects stored in Firestore is going to change
AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK.
To hide this warning and ensure your app does not break, you need to add the
following code to your app before calling any other Cloud Firestore methods:

  const firestore = new Firestore();
  const settings = {/* your settings... */ timestampsInSnapshots: true};
  firestore.settings(settings);

With this change, timestamps stored in Cloud Firestore will be read back as
Firebase Timestamp objects instead of as system Date objects. So you will also
need to update code expecting a Date to instead expect a Timestamp. For example:

  // Old:
  const date = snapshot.get('created_at');
  // New:
  const timestamp = snapshot.get('created_at');
  const date = timestamp.toDate();

Please audit all existing usages of Date when you enable the new behavior. In a
future release, the behavior will change to the new behavior, so if you do not
follow these steps, YOUR APP MAY BREAK.
```

As a result, I added

```
const firestore = new Firestore();
const settings = {timestampsInSnapshots: true};
firestore.settings(settings);
```

But I receive this error when deploying :

```
Firestore is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started getting the "Cannot read property 'seconds' of null" error last week as well. For me it seems to only show up when trying to commit a batch with no sets/updates/deletes. Are you using batches?

Regarding the `timestampsInSeconds` error, try using `admin.firestore()` instead of `Firestore()` (but still configuring the settings).

Would be nice to get some guidance on this from the Firebase team, as they haven't really addressed timestamsInSeconds for functions.

EDIT:

Today I added code to only call batch.commit() if batch._writes.length > 0, and it seems to prevent the "'seconds' of null" error. Kind of sloppy, but it will work until Firebase fixes their code.

Comment: I think I am commiting a batch wth no sets or updates , because I query if there are any posts that are over the time stamp and if so I delete them. Thus, if no posts are there then there will be nothing in the batch. I’ll try implementing a counter and see if that fixes it , I got the admin.firestore to work, too. Thanks for the help

Comment: The counter fixed it. Just added a counter that increments for each item in the collection, if it was greater than zero then return the batch else return null.